# Unweighted GPA Calculator Code code problem

Tags: vb.net

I want the user to input credit hours in the TextBox, select grade from the ComboBox for the number of rows generated based on the semester course number entered.
And the code for generating the rows is in the Form1_Load event and the code for calculating the GPA is to be done in the CHECK GPA button. The problem am having is how to save all the credit hours and grades and calculate it.
Here is the code:

```
Imports System.Windows.Forms

Public Class Form1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Me.Show()

    Dim Answer As String '= InputBox("Enter number of rows:", "Input Row ", "0")
    Dim Row As Integer '= CInt(Answer)
    Dim Height As Integer
    Dim Valid As Boolean = False

    Do While Valid = False
        Try
            Dim Repeat = True
            Do While Repeat = True
                Answer = InputBox("Please Enter Number Of Semester Courses:", "GPA CHECKER", "0")
                Row = CInt(Answer)
                If Row > 0 And Row <= 13 Then
                    Repeat = False
                Else
                    Repeat = True
                End If
            Loop

            Valid = True
        Catch ex As InvalidCastException
            MsgBox("You Can Only Input Numbers!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
            Valid = False
        End Try
    Loop

    For index As Integer = 1 To Row

        Dim myPanel As New Panel
        Dim myLabel As New Label
        Dim myTextBox As New TextBox
        Dim myComboBox As New ComboBox

        myPanel.Name = "myPanel" + index.ToString
        myPanel.Location = New Point(12, 70 + Height)
        myPanel.Size = New Size(260, 34)

        myLabel.Text = "Course" + index.ToString
        myLabel.Size = New Size(80, 22)
        myLabel.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft
        myLabel.Location = New Point(45, 12)

        myTextBox.Name = "CreditHours"
        myTextBox.Size = New Size(50, 22)
        myTextBox.Location = New Size(125, 12)

        myComboBox.Name = "Grade"
        myComboBox.Size = New Size(50, 22)
        myComboBox.Location = New Size(210, 12)
        myComboBox.Items.Add("A+")
        myComboBox.Items.Add("A")
        myComboBox.Items.Add("B+")
        myComboBox.Items.Add("B")
        myComboBox.Items.Add("C+")
        myComboBox.Items.Add("C")
        myComboBox.Items.Add("D+")
        myComboBox.Items.Add("D")
        myComboBox.Items.Add("F")

        myPanel.Controls.Add(myLabel)
        myPanel.Controls.Add(myTextBox)
        myPanel.Controls.Add(myComboBox)

        Me.Controls.Add(myPanel)

        Height += 34

        Me.Show()

    Next

End Sub

Private Sub btnCheckGpa_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnCheckGpa.Click


    Form2.Show()
    Me.Hide()

End Sub

Private Sub btnExit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnExit.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: This is a weighted average based on the number of credit hours. A 4 credit course will have more effect on the GPA than a 3 credit course.

Comment: What numeric values are associated with each grade? It used to be A=4, B=3, C=2, D = 1 and F=0. So what do you want for A+, B+ etc.?